# What font is used in agora.io logo

Tags: font-identification

I've tried several font identification website and all failed to find anything close.

The first letter 'a' is customised designed, but hope to get some help to identify from the rest of the letters 'gora.io'

[image]

Comment: most probably all letters are customized, based on one or more typefaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help others, it's a combination of Shadeerah Soft and Danube (thanks to @Bijutoha).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you call upon to answer an especially difficult question right now! Most likely, this kind of question that have no satisfying answers!

This looks like "DANUBE FONT"! It is one kind of modifying an existing typeface to create a unique logo! https://www.ffonts.net/Danube.font?text=OraIO

[image]

Check the last 2 letters. Same as the "Danube" I hope, you read my mind!

Comment: quite the stretch, the "i" and "o" are the only letters that sort of match... but who knows.

Comment: Thanks @Bijutoha, following your suggestion, seem it's a combination of "Shadeerah" and "Danube"